# WebApi Custom MediaTypeFormatter get posted parameters

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am calling a post action on a webapi by passing in a serialised JSON DTO.

I also have a custom media type formatter to encrypt the resulting data.  However in the WriteToStreamAsync method, how can i get the posted parameters?

The custom media type formatter class

```
public class JsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{


    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var taskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
               //How to get posted parameters?
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskSource.SetException(e);
        }
        return taskSource.Task;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it via the HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream

Answer (score 0):

Using `HttpContext.Current` generally should not work in this scenario since it won't always be available for `async` calls.

Instead do something like this:

```
    public class JsonFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        private readonly HttpRequestMessage request;

        public JsonFormatter() { }
        public JsonFormatter(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            this.request = request;
        }

        public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            return new JsonFormatter(request);
        }

        public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            // logic referencing this.request
        }
    }
```